# Blackberry simulator hangs under Windows VM guest

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I run Ubuntu 10.10 x64 but use a Windows 7 x64 and Windows XP x86 VM to use Windows. I am trying to get the Blackberry simulator and the Eclipse load-to-device features to work.

The simulator is just a transparent window that completely locks up. Though I can package the app no problem, when I choose load-to-device Eclipse hangs.

Though the phone is detected and I am giving it enough resources, I am thinking maybe this is because it is a virtual machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try turning off graphics acceleration. In an open simulator, View->Graphics Acceleration->Off. Worked for me.